# Adobe Dreamweaver crash on launch: Error 6

Tags: crash, dreamweaver, adobe-cs5, application-launch

Have **Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5** installed on Windows 8 and first install, it's working properly, but after some time on next launch I get Error:

> Please uninstall and reinstall the product.
>
> Error 6

.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

I tried to fix it by this way: [Adobe Help](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/restore-preferences-dreamweaver-cs4-cs5.html#main_Restore7V), but not success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`Error 6` appears to be a very generic term in that people have resolved it in many different ways.

These have included

Reformat the hard drive. I hope this isn't necessary but, depending on your situation, it may be a "quick" fix. [Source](http://support.muse.adobe.com/thread/1109972?tstart=0)

An issue with the license (not found/recognized/valid/expired etc). [You could try and reset it.](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/error-licensing-stopped-windows.html)

As per your post, [resetting the preferences some times helps](http://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/kb/restore-preferences-dreamweaver-cs4-cs5.html#main_Restore7V)

Make sure you're running as an administrator. You can even right click and "run as administrator" to see if the fault is with permissions.

A reinstall may be required with your antivirus switched off.

You may have corrupted hard drive, run scandisc /f from command prompt.

Also, make sure you have the latest update and all patches etc are installed.

Comment: I tried everything except reformatting hard drive, but no success.
How reformatting can fix this?

Comment: @zur4ik, I don't know if it will, this is the problem. When you entered the license a key, I will assume some form of key was stored on your computer, in the registry may be but, something is saved to tell the program that you are licensed. If this key is corrupted then maybe the clean ups you've tried are not helping as the program thinks the key already exists. I'm not saying this is the case, but this is how a reformat *may* work. If it was me, I'd try and get in touch with Adobe direct!

Comment: @zur4ik, what ever the case, please do not swear. People of all ages are free to use this website. I admit having to pay for the service does seem unfair/unjust, but for the sake of $40 it may be the fastest way to get it done! Especially as you've tried so many other options! Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: ok, thank you anyway. You tried more then Adobe Support team :)

Answer (score 0):

Do the followings:

1. C: drive in search Dreamweaver.
2. Then all folder display and delete all Dreamweaver Folder.
3. Then install Dreamweaver.

I'm very much sure this will work.